# Using the Constant Contact C# .net-sdk v2 to create/add

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, constantcontact

I'm using the official version 2 of the Constant Contact .net-sdk found [here](https://github.com/constantcontact/.net-sdk).

I've been unable to find methods for the following:

- Creating a Contact List
- Adding a contact to a Contact List
- Removing a contact from a Contact List
- Adding multiple contacts to a Contact List
- Creating an Email Campaign

These features clearly exist in v2 of the [API found here](https://constantcontact.mashery.com/io-docs), but seem missing from the SDK.

Any help in accessing this functionality is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check this link? https://github.com/constantcontact/.net-sdk/blob/master/ContactExample/CTCTWrapper_Contact/Form1.cs

Comment: `Form1.cs` only shows how to add a contact to the global contacts.  It does not show how to add or remove a contact from a Contact List or any of the other tasks mentioned in the question above.  Though I might be able to apply the following syntax `contact.Lists.Add(new ContactList() { Id = "1", Status = Status.Active });`

Comment: Well, Api docs reference is here for delete http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-resource.html?method=DELETE
I used HttpClient to create a contact.

Comment: Are you going to share you answer?

Comment: I can share create contact using HTTPClient(not a library) if you want..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84118/discussion-between-deepu-and-nu-everest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Contact.

```
try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "<Replace with your oAuth Token>");

        ContactObject cont = new ContactObject
        {
            first_name = "Deepu",
            last_name = "Madhusoodanan"
        };

        var email_addresses = new List<EmailAddress>
        {
            new EmailAddress{email_address = "deepumi1@gmail.com"}
        };

        cont.email_addresses = email_addresses;
        cont.lists = new List<List>
        {
            new List {id = "<Replace with your List Id>"}
        };

        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cont);
        string MessageType = "application/json";
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts?api_key=<Replace with your API key>"))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", MessageType);

            request.Content = new StringContent(json);
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(MessageType);

            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                string responseXml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var code = response.StatusCode;
            }
            request.Content.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exp)
{ 
  //log exception here
}

/*Model class*/
public class Address
{
    public string address_type { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country_code { get; set; }
    public string line1 { get; set; }
    public string line2 { get; set; }
    public string line3 { get; set; }
    public string postal_code { get; set; }
    public string state_code { get; set; }
    public string sub_postal_code { get; set; }
}

public class List
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddress
{
    public string email_address { get; set; }
}

public class ContactObject
{
    public List<Address> addresses { get; set; }
    public List<List> lists { get; set; }
    public string cell_phone { get; set; }
    public string company_name { get; set; }
    public bool confirmed { get; set; }
    public List<EmailAddress> email_addresses { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string home_phone { get; set; }
    public string job_title { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string middle_name { get; set; }
    public string prefix_name { get; set; }
    public string work_phone { get; set; }
}
```

Note : You have to replace oAuth token, API key and List id.

Delete method based on the api document.(http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-resource.html?method=DELETE)

Note : I have not tested the delete method yet.

```
private async Task<string> DeleteContact(string contactId)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "<Replace with your oAuth Token>");
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Delete, "https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts/" + contactId + "?api_key=<Replace with your API key>"))
            {
                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    { 
        //log exp here
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: This is not fully compliant with v2 of the API, but it is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @nueverest : can you explain what I am missing?

Comment: Instead of `cont.lists = new List<List>` you could use `cont.lists = new List<ContactList>`.  Instead of `new EmailAddress{email_address = "email@gmail.com"}` you could use `new EmailAddress{EmailAddr = "email@gmail.com"}`.  That way you wouldn't have to create the `ContactList` or `EmailAddress` classes yourself as they already exist in v2 of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for adding a contact. What I did was combine the code that Deepu provided with the Constant Contact API v2. I also had to remove `async` and `await` references because they are incompatible with VS2010.  I have not tried `DELETE` yet...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Http;
using CTCT.Components.Contacts;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

/// <summary>
/// Constant Contact Helper Class for POST, PUT, and DELETE 
/// </summary>
public class ConstantContactHelper
{
    private string _accessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ccAccessToken"];
    private Dictionary<string, System.Net.Http.HttpMethod> requestDict = new Dictionary<string, System.Net.Http.HttpMethod> { 
        {"GET", HttpMethod.Get}, 
        {"POST", HttpMethod.Post}, 
        {"PUT", HttpMethod.Put}, 
        {"DELETE", HttpMethod.Delete} 
    };
    private System.Net.Http.HttpMethod requestMethod = null;
    private Dictionary<string, ConstantContactURI> uriDict = new Dictionary<string, ConstantContactURI> { 
        {"AddContact", new ConstantContactURI("contacts")},
        {"AddContactList", new ConstantContactURI("lists")},
        {"AddEmailCampaign", new ConstantContactURI("campaigns")},
    };
    private ConstantContactURI URI_Handler = new ConstantContactURI();
    private ContactRequestBody RequestBody = new ContactRequestBody();
    private const string messageType = "application/json";
    public string jsonRequest = null;
    public string responseXml = null;
    public string status_code = null;

    public ConstantContactHelper()  {}

    public ConstantContactHelper(string methodKey, string uriKey, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string listId)
    {
        this.requestMethod = this.requestDict[methodKey];
        this.URI_Handler = this.uriDict[uriKey];
        this.RequestBody = new ContactRequestBody(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, listId);
    }

    // Return Response as a string
    public void TryRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", this._accessToken);

                var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.RequestBody.contact);
                this.jsonRequest = json;
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, this.URI_Handler.fullURI))
                {
                    request.Headers.Add("Accept", messageType);

                    request.Content = new StringContent(json);
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(messageType);

                    using (var response = client.SendAsync(request))
                    {
                        this.responseXml = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).ToString();
                        this.status_code = response.Status.ToString();
                    }
                    request.Content.Dispose();                    
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            // Handle Exception
            this.responseXml = "Unhandled exception: " + exp.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public class ConstantContactURI
{
    private const string baseURI = "https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/";
    private const string queryPrefix = "?api_key=";
    private string _apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ccApiKey"];
    public string fullURI = null;

    public ConstantContactURI() {}

    public ConstantContactURI(string specificPath)
    {
        this.fullURI = baseURI + specificPath + queryPrefix + _apiKey;    
    }
}

public class ContactRequestBody
{
    public Contact contact = new Contact();

    private List<EmailAddress> email_addresses = new List<EmailAddress>()
    {
        new EmailAddress{
            EmailAddr = "",
            Status = Status.Active,
            ConfirmStatus = ConfirmStatus.NoConfirmationRequired
        }
    };
    private List<ContactList> lists = new List<ContactList>()
    {
        new ContactList {Id = ""}
    };

    public ContactRequestBody() { }

    public ContactRequestBody(string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string listId) 
    {
        this.contact.FirstName = firstName;
        this.contact.LastName = lastName;

        this.email_addresses[0].EmailAddr = emailAddress;
        this.contact.EmailAddresses = this.email_addresses;

        this.lists[0].Id = listId;
        this.contact.Lists = this.lists;
    }
}
```

An Example call from an `aspx.cs` page looks like this:

```
ConstantContactHelper requestHelper = new ConstantContactHelper("POST", "AddContact", firstName.Text, lastName.Text, emailBox.Text, listId);
requestHelper.TryRequest();
lbTest.Text = requestHelper.jsonRequest + ", status code:" + requestHelper.status_code + ", xml:" + requestHelper.responseXml;
```